# Sort list of list in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have this list structure:

```
[[[6], [4], 1.0], [[5, 6], [4], 1.0], [[5], [6], 1.0], [[5], [4, 6], 1.0], [[5], [4], 1.0], [[4, 5], [6], 1.0], [[4], [6], 0.8]]
```

And I want to sort it via the 3rd element (descending order) and the lengths of the first and second list (first the ones which are smaller). I tried using

```
r = sorted(r, key=itemgetter(2, 0, 1), reverse=True)
```

which sorts the 3rd element in descending order, but how can I add the other sorting restrictions to this one?

Expected output:

```
[[[6], [4], 1.0], [[5], [6], 1.0], [[5], [6], 1.0], [[5], [4], 1.0], [[5], [4, 6], 1.0], [[5, 6], [4], 1.0], [[4, 5], [6], 1.0], [[4], [6], 0.8]]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @DeepSpace I edited the question to show you the expected output. But basically as I said, I want it to be sorted first given the 3rd element, and then for the length of the first and second list (shortest first)

Comment: @JHBonarius yeah sorry, now it is corrected

Comment: @JHBonarius no its not a duplicate, I need 2 sorting restrictions in this case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [lambda expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
r = sorted(r, key=lambda x:(x[2], -len(x[0]), -len(x[1])), reverse=True)
```

or sort without reassignment:

```
r.sort(key=lambda x:(x[2], -len(x[0]), -len(x[1])), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Almost right. you need to inverse the size, because he wants the smallest first `r.sort(key=lambda x:(x[2], -len(x[0]), -len(x[1])), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you could do this in one line, you would need to do in stages like this, with the primary key last:

```
a = [[[6], [4], 1.0], [[5, 6], [4], 1.0], [[5], [6], 1.0], [[5], [4, 6], 1.0],
     [[5], [4], 1.0], [[4, 5], [6], 1.0], [[4], [6], 0.8]]
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x : len(x[1]), reverse=False)
c = sorted(b, key=lambda x : len(x[0]), reverse=False)
d = sorted(c, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
```

This gives the correct result:

`>>> d
[[[6], [4], 1.0], [[5], [6], 1.0], [[5], [6], 1.0], [[5], [4], 1.0], [[5], [4, 6], 1.0], [[5, 6], [4], 1.0], [[4, 5], [6], 1.0], [[4], [6], 0.8]]`

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) for more information.